# Best practises for Schema migration in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I want to know whats the recommended practise for schema migration in mongo.I know in sql we can create .sql script file and add all the sql commands and run it so that it gets decoupled with code .But about mongo db .Do we write everything in code like creating collection ,indexes as such

Comment: Yes, why not? Of course, this syntax is different but like in SQL you can create collections (usually not needed, because they are created automatically), indexes, users, etc.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I didnt get you .Can you elaborate more with examples if possible

Comment: I don't get you either. Simply write all commands and save as `.js` file. Then you can execute it in the same way as you run an .sql file (using the `mongo` shell of course)